# iOS 17 background shows abnormally

Tags: css, ios, ios17

In new version iOS 17.0.0 css property filter: blur() not working.

Is there any other method to do blur effect on iOS?

```
.loader__background {
    background-color: red;
    -webkit-filter: blur(84px);
    filter: blur(84px);
    z-index: 1;
}
```

[How its shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71IWt.jpg)